# Can I load a multi-frame TIFF through OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv

Anyone know if OpenCV is capable of loading a multi-frame TIFF stack? 
I'm using OpenCV 2.2.0 with python 2.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately OpenCV does not support TIFF directories and is able to read only the first frame from multi-frame TIFF files.

Comment: OpenCV has added this functionality, as it is present in version 3.4.  See: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga4dd47c9ae3d55cc42286cff005825e31

Answer (score 13):

OpenCV is now capable of reading a multi-page TIFF using the `imreadmulti` function.  See this page from the OpenCV 3.4 documentation:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga4dd47c9ae3d55cc42286cff005825e31

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I'd just add that it's important to set the right [flags](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80). If you want the separate channels/pages to be read as is, use for example `flags=cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`.

Answer (score 10):

While OpenCV can't open multi-frame TIFF files, you can open the image using PIL and then pass the data on to OpenCV.  I haven't yet been able to get it working with the new "cv2" namespace

```
tiff = Image.open('sample.tif')
try:
    while 1:
        # Convert PIL image to OpenCV
        image = cv.CreateImageHeader(tiff.size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
        cv.SetData(image, tiff.tostring()) # It's "tostring" and not "toString()"!
        # Do whatever you're going to do with OpenCV data
        tiff.seek(tiff.tell()+1)
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In case anyone else cares, I got it working in ``cv2``. Further, I made a class that emulates the behavior of a ``cv2`` capture object, you can treat multi-frame TIFF files just like a movie file. See the class ``PseudoCapture``: https://github.com/danielballan/mr/blob/master/mr/video/tiff.py

Comment: @Dan Allan I'm very interested but this link is broken now, could you provide the script please?

Comment: I split the image-reading stuff into a separate repository that I am calling ``pims``. It lives on this organization page now: https://github.com/soft-matter/pims

Comment: P.S. If you get some use out of this, get in touch! I'd like to see more people using it, giving feedback, contributing changes. Cheers!

Comment: @Corey Cole, apparently there is no support for the function `CreateImageHeader` in OpenCV 3.3, is there any alternative to that?

Answer (score 5):

You can load multi-frame tiff files in OpenCV using file read function called imreadmulti.
Here is the example

```
 ret, images = cv2.imreadmulti('<path_of_tiff_files>.tiff', [], cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
```

Images will be a list of frames in the tiff file. Suppose you want to see 2nd image, you can access as

```
img = images[1] # note 0 based indexing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also load and access tiff stacks in OpenCV after pip install [TiffCapture](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/TiffCapture). It implements all the VideoCapture methods you'd expect in OpenCV for tiffs using PIL.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#cv2.__version__ == '4.5.1'

_, frame_data = cv2.imreadmulti('my.tiff', [], cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

#or

_, frame_data = cv2.imreadmulti('my.tiff', [], -1)
```

Comment: since you chose to add an answer that is _very_ similar to an existing answer, you really should point out how your answer differs, how does it behave differently, and _why_ that matters.