Read 4 channel images with CV2 for Semantic segmentation
I'I'm working on a Unet semantic segmentation project where I need to process 4-channel images using OpenCV in Python, and I'm new to this field. I found a tutorial on YouTube (link to tutorial) for the same purpose, but the code provided in the tutorial uses RGB and cv2.imread() to read images, which I believe doesn't work for 4-channel images.
My goal is to adapt the provided code to work with 4-channel images, but I'm not sure how to modify it accordingly.
Here's a simplified version of the code from the tutorial:
import os
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

temp_img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/PREDATOR/Desktop/4_channel_image.tif')
temp_img = cv2.cvtColor(temp_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(temp_img)

and this the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 2
      1 temp_img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/PREDATOR/Desktop/4_channel_image.tif')
----> 2 temp_img = cv2.cvtColor(temp_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
      3 plt.imshow(temp_img) #change 0 to 1 2 or 3 to view other channels"""
    

error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:196: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'


What is your 4th channel? Did you try the flag IMREAD_UNCHANGED in your cv2.imread()?  I have no idea if that will work, but worth a try.

@fmw42 my image is an RGB with NDVI  as forth channel

@fmw42 I tried IMREAD_UNCHANGED, and the image displays correctly. However, temp_img.shape returns (9258, 7451, 3) instead of (9258, 7451, 4). Any ideas on why the 4th channel might not be included?

Kindly share your image. Google Drive/Dropbox/Github or some service that doesn't alter images.

After reading in OpenCV, does the image actually have 4 channels?  I suspect the 4th channel got removed when reading the image into OpenCV.  So post your image as Mark suggested above.  What is NDVI?  Sorry it does not ring a bell?

@fmw42 NDVI  is "Normalised Difference Vegetation Index" and is a measure of likeliness that a pixel is vegetation in a satellite image. It relies on high reflectance in the Near InfraRed channel.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335308/can-i-load-a-multi-frame-tiff-through-opencv using cv2. imreadmulti()

Sorry, I think imreadmulti() is for reading multi-page tiff, not multi-channel. But might be worth trying.

Imagemagick can read multi-channel TIFF. So you could try Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick.

tifffile can also read such TIFFs, see https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/

I tried tifffile.imread(image_path) and it worked, thank you so much. And as @fmw42 said cv2.imreadmulti() didn't work.

Post your code as an answer so others can benefit

I tried the code below and it worked:
import os
import tifffile
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

temp_img = tifffile.imread('C:/Users/PREDATOR/Desktop/4_channel_image.tif')
plt.imshow(temp_img)

